# strange error on shared memory for windows 7

Tags: c++, windows

Trying to learn some basics on shared memory for windows 7.  I created the following based on an example, it compiles fine,  when I run it as

```
c:\temp> a.exe  tmp.txt 85
```

It didn't produced 10 bytes from the file as I expected, instead, it just printed 10 null bytes.   Any idea why?

Thanks

==============here is the test program=============

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>


int _tmain(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   HANDLE hMapFile;
   LPCTSTR pBuf;
    //printf("argv[1] %s\n", argv[1]); exit(0);
   hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
                 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
                 NULL,                    // default security
                 PAGE_READONLY,          // read/write access
                 0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
                 atoi(argv[2]),            // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
                 argv[1]);                 // name of mapping object

   if (hMapFile == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),
             GetLastError());
      return 1;
   }
   pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,   // handle to map object
                        FILE_MAP_READ,     // read/write permission
                        0,
                        0,
                        atoi(argv[2]));  //BUF_SIZE);

   if (pBuf == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
             GetLastError());

       CloseHandle(hMapFile);

      return 1;
   }
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", pBuf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing empty memory, which is why you are seeing nulls.  You have to put something in the memory to have something other than zeros.  As you can see on the `MapViewOfFile` documentation, mapped views of the pagefile are always initialized to contain only zeros.

You've correctly allocated a read only section in memory, backed by the page file.  You won't be able to write to it, because it is read only.  However, if you were to make it writable, you'd be able to write some bytes into memory, and then read them back.

Conversely, you could use an existing file to back the mapping, and assuming the file wasn't empty, you would be able to read bytes from that file.  It looks like, based on that arguments you invoke the program with, you are trying to map tmp.txt.  If that is the case, you need to open that file using CreateFile and then pass the resulting `HANDLE` as the first parameter to `CreateFileMapping`.  Once you do that, the output should match the contents of the file.

The code below assumes a 64bit system and an all ASCII filename.  It also doesn't clean up resources from CreateFileA, CreateFileMappingA or MapViewOfFile.

```
void map_file(const char * fname) {
    HANDLE file = CreateFileA(fname, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        throw runtime_error("Unable to open file");
    }

    LARGE_INTEGER file_size = {0};
    if (!GetFileSizeEx(file, &file_size)) {
        throw runtime_error("Unable to get file size");
    }

    if (file_size.QuadPart == 0) {
        throw runtime_error("File cannot be empty");
    }

    HANDLE mapping = CreateFileMappingA(file, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
    if (mapping == nullptr) {
        throw runtime_error("Unable to map file");
    }

    uint8_t * view = (uint8_t *) MapViewOfFile(mapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, (size_t) file_size.QuadPart);
    if (view == nullptr) {
        throw runtime_error("Unable to map view of file");
    }

    // do something with 'view'
}
```

Comment: Thanks @superultranova for the quick answer.  My confusion is, why doesn't it print the data in the file that I passed to `CreateFileMapping(.. argv[1])`?  the file is a ascii file with 85 bytes.

Comment: The name of the mapping object isn't the name of the file you want to map, it is a name you want to give to the mapping object so you can reference it later.  It doesn't have anything to do with the file.  The handle to the open file is supposed to be passed as the first argument to CreateFileMapping.  For your purposes, you can set the last argument to CreateFileMapping as NULL, you don't need it right now.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, have fun!  Just saw an error in the CreateFileA call, so I fixed that.